# Unable to assign a random string to _id field.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I am trying to save a document into mongodb using [MONK](https://github.com/LearnBoost/monk) drive.

My object has a field called myid, which is a string of unknown length. I'm very inclined to use this ID as _id of my document but after I assign the value to _id field and save the document, I receive error as below:

```
Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 
hex characters
```

Is this some restriction introduced by MONK or MongoDB driver? Is there anyway to workaround this? In mongodb shell, you can use any value as _id;

Comment: I do not believe this is a MongoDB error as such I would say this is imposed by MONK, you would probably want to open and issue there

Comment: How are you actually updating? To clarify Monk is trying to "cast" `_id` values into an ObjectId, hence the message.

Comment: Neil, thanks. I understood it now but really hate this "feature". It imposes unnecessary restriction on the choice of value for _id field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an error thrown by monk. You can override the id function:

```
collectionName.id = function(str){return str;};
```

See: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Automattic/monk/issues/76)